# Creating a histogram from a subset created from the subset function

Tags: r, csv, histogram, subset

This is how I've retrieved my dataset, everything is good so far.

```
> mantis<-read.csv("mantis.csv")
> attach(mantis)
```

The dataset provides numerical data on body mass/length/claw strength/etc. of FEMALE and MALE mantises. The object is to create a histogram showing the body masses of ONLY female mantises. I created a subset;

```
> mantis_sub<-subset(mantis, Sex=="f",select="Body.Mass.g")
```

Then I tried;

```
> hist(mantis_sub)
Error in hist.default(mantis_sub) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I've searched this link;
[Plot a histogram of subset of a data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284591/plot-a-histogram-of-subset-of-a-data)
...and I cannot figure out how to properly create this histogram. I am unfortunately not fluent enough in R to understand the solution and the textbook I'm using does not cover this.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `mantis_sub` is a dataframe (ie a table of body masses, lengths, claw strengths, ..), not a set of numbers, so `hist` is unsure which column you wish to plot.

You need to extract the column you want to do a histogram of. To do this you put `mantis_sub${column name}`. The dollar sign extracts the appropriate column from the `mantis_sub` table.

e.g. to do a histogram of the column named "BodyMass"

```
hist(mantis_sub$BodyMass)
```

If you want to do histograms of many columns automatically, then you'll have to loop through them, e.g.

```
for (column in c("BodyMass", "ClawStrength")) {
    hist(mantis_sub[[column]])
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer :). Thanks a lot.